# I want to hide the continue button in the checkout process

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I have a magento website i built a custom shipping module for the site but now i want to hide the continue button when an error message of my choice is shown. To stop customers from carrying on with making a payment.

Can anyone help???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi waseem, As per the scenario the consumer will be in checkout page . if any error occurs in shipping method section .It will not proceed to payment method section ?

Comment: Hi mageotron. Yes that is correct if there is an error msg then they can not go further, at the moment they can and i want to stop that.